# SQL Leavers Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query to show Employee Leavers for past 30 days. The employees are removed from the report if the paperwork received column is Y and it has been 30 days. But if the paperwork received column is N and it is past 30 days they should still be on the report. I am looking for a query that can have this result. The below query is what i have but it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT
a.emp_no,
a.date_of_leaving,
b.INTERNAL_DISPLAY_NAME AS NAME,
b.free_field1 as paperwork_received
FROM
emp_employed_time_row a
LEFT JOIN COMPANY_PERSON_ALL B 
ON a.emp_no = b.emp_no
WHERE
emp_employed_time_api.get_date_of_leaving(a.company_id, a.emp_no, SYSDATE) BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 
'mm')-30/*current month*/ AND SYSDATE
AND emp_employed_time_api.get_date_of_leaving(a.company_id, a.emp_no, SYSDATE) BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE, 
'yyyy') AND SYSDATE
```

Current Results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDS4X.jpg)
Desired Results
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWGuN.jpg)

So after 30 days, Employee A and B should be removed from the report as paperwork received is Y but Employee C should still be on the report as paperwork received is N. After paperwork received is changed to Y then Employee C is removed from the report.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: attached images of the results and desired results

Answer (score 0):

Your updated query should look alike -

```
SELECT a.emp_no,
       a.date_of_leaving,
       b.INTERNAL_DISPLAY_NAME AS NAME,
       b.free_field1 as paperwork_received
FROM emp_employed_time_row a
LEFT JOIN COMPANY_PERSON_ALL B ON a.emp_no = b.emp_no
WHERE (emp_employed_time_api.get_date_of_leaving(a.company_id, a.emp_no, SYSDATE) - SYSDATE >= 30 AND b.free_field1 = 'Y')
```

Comment: Thanks. The query brings back everyone who has left the company and future leavers. I would like to show the leavers for the past 30 days?

Comment: @Yasir, Try now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
a.emp_no,
a.date_of_leaving,
b.INTERNAL_DISPLAY_NAME AS NAME,
b.free_field1 as paperwork_received,
emp_employed_time_api.get_date_of_leaving(a.company_id, a.emp_no, SYSDATE) as leaving_dt,
sysdate as todayy
FROM
emp_employed_time_row a
LEFT JOIN COMPANY_PERSON_ALL B 
ON a.emp_no = b.emp_no
and (
    case when sysdate-emp_employed_time_api.get_date_of_leaving(a.company_id, a.emp_no, SYSDATE) >= 30
         then 
             case when b.free_field1 = 'Y' then 0 
                  when b.free_field1 = 'N' then 1
                  else 1  /* case: paperwork received is null? */
              end
         else 1 /* case: leaving date < 30 days */
    end
);
```

Comment: Thanks but i am getting the "invalid relational operator" error for the last closed bracket on line 21?

Comment: Please try now. modified the brackets.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i am getting the same error "invalid relational operator" Error at Line: 21 Column: 1

Comment: Tough luck. Then perhaps you can cosider giving some ddl to create the tables and sample records if you want syntax validated for you.If we have the tables we can give you sql which works.